# Can someone help with these passages Sartre's BeIng and Nothingness on Knowledge?

Tags: existentialism, phenomenology, sartre

P295 ‘The for itself does not exist subsequently to know; neither can we say that it exists only in so far it knows or is known…regulated by particular bits of Knowledge.’

P296 ‘to say that there is being is nothing, and yet it is to affect a total metamorphosis since there is being only for a for-itself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97304/discussion-on-question-by-deepthinker101-can-someone-help-with-these-passages-sa).

Comment: Also if it is the pure negation of being why does he say that there is a being of the for-itself?

Comment: Hi I cannot use the discussion due to the fact my rep is too low, can you please give this question an upvote?

Comment: Upvote added - okay ?

Comment: Thank you very much